# Firebase Functions - Cannot get collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

first time working with scheduled Firebase Functions. I have the problem, that the following code does not return a collection.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();



export const setOverdue = functions.region("europe-west1").pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async () => {
    const usercollection = await admin.firestore().collection("user").get();
    console.log(usercollection.docs.length); <-- This is always "0", even tho i have multiple user obkects
    
});
```

Comment: Can you show the data you have in `user`?

Comment: user contains 10ish documents which all contain a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i used the wrong region:

```
r.region("europe-west1")
```

changed to

```
r.region("europe-west3")
```

and it worked